# junit test and non junit test with ant target

Tags: spring, ant, junit

```
<junit printsummary="on" fork="yes" forkmode="once" 
haltonerror="false" haltonfailure="false" 
    failureproperty="junit.failure" showoutput="false" maxmemory="1024m">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/> 
        <dirset dir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}"/>
    </classpath>            
    <batchtest fork="no"  todir="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}">
         <fileset dir="${COMP_TEST_SRC}">                   
              <include name="**/*Test.java" />
              <include name="**/Test*.java" />
              <exclude name="**/EswTestCase.java" />
         </fileset>             
    </batchtest>    
    <formatter type="xml" />            
</junit>
```

this takes lot of time to generate xml report, and it thorws following error:

```
Caught an exception while logging the end of the build.  Exception was:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

why it takes long time to genearte xml? how to resolve this error and make application to run fast. I have only max of 10 test files. I use command promt to execute ant script.

**Analysis:**

1)If i run batch test only for test calss which extends Junit test it execute very fast. eg:

> public class ImpactsParserTest extends
>   **TestCase**{..

2)Now if i have test class which extends spring junit test as:

> public class AddressLookupServiceTest
>   extends **EswTestCase**{..
>
> public class EswTestCase extends
>   **AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests{..**

this causes junit target to run very slowly and causes outof memory error. why itis happening like this?

3) when I make batchtest fork="yes" instead of no, then build is quick and doesnt throw outof memory. But, it throws error like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:118)
..
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bgc.ordering.wizard.back.services.EswTestCase
```

even though, i have specified these jar file and class file in classpath element as:

and logger jar in

```
<path id="CLASSPATH_JUNIT">
   <fileset dir="${BUILD_LIBS_HOME}">       
       <include name="*.jar" /> 
   </fileset>
   <pathelement location="${TEST_CLASSES_DIR}" />
   <pathelement location="${TEST_BUILD_DIR}" />
   <pathelement location="${COMP_BUILD}" />     
   <pathelement location="${COMP_CLASSES}" />   
   <path location="${APP_DIR}\bgc-esw-services\target\classes"/> 
   <pathelement location="${APP_DIR}\bgc-esw-web\target\classes" />
```

...

log4j.properties present at `${TEST_BUILD_DIR}`

using: apache-ant-1.8.1 and junit-3.8.1.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when the JVM runs out of space in the permanent generation heap. The memory in the Virtual Machine is divided into a number of regions. One of these regions is PermGen. It's an area of memory that is used to (among other things) load class files. The size of this memory region is fixed, i.e. it does not change when the VM is running. You can specify the size of this region with a commandline switch: `-XX:MaxPermSize`. The default is 64 Mb on the Sun VMs. To fix this issue you can give it a higher value like 256mb.

My guess is that you not only run unit tests you also run integration tests e.g. you have a class wired with Spring and you require their dependencies. That's why you have `EswTestCase`. If you just want to write unit tests I'd recommend you instantiate your class and mock the dependencies to other classes that you are not testing directly. This will minimize your memory footprint because you don't have to create your Spring application context.

This is what the [JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests.html) says about `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests`:

> Really for integration testing, not
>   unit testing. You should not normally
>   use the Spring container for unit
>   tests: simply populate your POJOs in
>   plain JUnit tests!

As of Spring 3.0, the legacy JUnit 3.8 base class hierarchy (i.e., AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests, AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests, etc.) is officially deprecated and will be removed in a later release. It is recommended that you use the [Spring TestContext Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework) for writing integration tests. Instead of extending `EswTestCase` with `AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests` you should use the annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class EswTestCase 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: (I have updated main question above.) this is good info, but If i make <batchtest fork="yes" instead of "no", then different error comes like logger not available( where this logger is reffered in ESWTestcase and other project dependent jar files) and EswTestCase class not found eventhough i have reffered classpath and logger path. one more point is, when fork=yes, then it doesnt through outof memory error and it is very fast.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that all your test cases that derive from `EswTestCase` fail. Not having to create a Spring application context will definitely be faster and will consume less memory. Your test report should show that they failed. It looks like your application libraries are not available in the classpath even though you declare them. I'd recommend you define them with an Ant `<path id="test.classpath"/>` and add them to your classpath with the Junit declaration like this `<classpath refid="test.classpath" />`.

Comment: i have referred as shown above in <path refid="CLASSPATH_JUNIT"/> and CLASSPATH_JUNIT is reffering logger and other jar files as shown above with updated content.

Comment: OK, got it. However, JUnit doesn't seem to find it. Can you print your path and check if it's actually there? I think this is how you can do it: `<echo message="${toString:CLASSPATH_JUNIT}"/>`. Alternatively, try to assign the complete JAR path and filename to `<pathelement location=".."/>` and see if that works.

Comment: it is printed as C:\build_libs\ESW\log4j-1.2.15.jar; and same jar exist in that location. suppose if it is not available, when i give fork=no then how it is working?

Comment: What version of Ant are you using?

Comment: Can you drop in a newer version of JUnit and see if it does the trick?

Comment: Not quite sure what's wrong with your classpath. So if you go down the route of not forking your tests why don't you just increase the PermGen size? That should fix your problem also.

Comment: where can i increase PermGen? i have already specified maxmemory="1024m", is this is correct? or some other place do i need to update?

Comment: The parameter `maxmemory` specifies the maximum amount of memory to allocate to the forked VM not the perm gen size. You have to specify it in your `ANT_OPTS`.

Comment: i have specified ANT_OPTS in system variable as -Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m. Still i get the error. How can i specify in build.xml?

Comment: You cannot specify the perm gen size in the build.xml as far as I could see. Try to print that environment variable before you run Ant. You should see the values you set.